# What are Typing Jet and De La Jet Set Radio?

Tags: gaming-history, jet-set-radio

On the tag wiki page for [jet-set-radio](/questions/tagged/jet-set-radio), I noticed that one of the listed platforms was [java-micro-edition](/questions/tagged/java-micro-edition), with two Japanese only releases from 2001 under the names *De La Jet Set Radio* and *Typing Jet*.

[image: Tag Wiki for Jet Set Radio]

What exactly are these Japanese-only versions of Jet Set Radio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What is *Typing Jet*?

*Typing Jet* was a Java typing game released for Japanese mobile phones in 2001. Players avoided obstacles and ran from the police by quickly typing characters.

It was unveiled alongside other mobile titles such as *Ulala's Channel J* (Based on Space Channel 5), *Columns Jr.*, and *The Typing of the Dead*.

[image: Only known screenshot of Typing Jet]

#### What about *De La Jet Set Radio*?

There was a game called *De La Jet Set Radio*, but it wasn't a Java mobile game. It was a re-released version of Jet Set Radio sold exclusively in Japan through Sega's Dreamcast direct service.

It included the extra levels, music, and characters from the European and American releases, along with several bug-fixes.

[image: Cover of 'De La Jet Set Radio']

#### Sources

- [セガ、J-フォンのJavaアプリ向けゲームサイト「セガ・パレード」](http://k-tai.watch.impress.co.jp/cda/article/news_toppage/5019.html) (Roughly translates to 'Sega, J-Phone game site for Java applications "Sega Parade"') (June 2001)
- [IGN - Sega's Cell Phone Titles Revealed](http://www.ign.com/articles/2001/06/01/segas-cell-phone-titles-revealed) (June 1, 2001)
- [JavaWorld - J2ME: The next major games platform?](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075085/mobile-java/j2me--the-next-major-games-platform-.html) (March 9, 2001)
- [SegaBits - SEGA Retrospective: Over the ‘hood, through the streets and right into your brain – It’s Jet Set Radio](http://segabits.com/blog/2014/04/28/over-the-hood-through-the-streets-and-right-into-your-brain-its-jet-set-radio-week/) (April 28, 2014)
- [Segagaga Domain - De La Jet Set Radio](http://www.segagagadomain.com/dreamcast-ntsc4/delajetset.htm)